# Retrieve mail quota from Exchange using java EWS API?

Tags: java, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using Microsoft's EWS API for Java (https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) and I want to read the mail quota (i.e. the memory limit and used memory) from our Exchange server for one mailbox.

For now, I can read the used memory by walking through the whole folder tree of a mailbox recursively and read the size of every folder (with extended properties).

For now, I'm searching for a way to read the limit of the whole mailbox (and a better way to read the used memory with a lower priority).

Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Can you post your solution or at least the significant parts of the code?

Comment: full solution in github, maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS doesn't surface the Mailbox quota information directly in Exchange 2013 there is a MailTip that will tell you if a Mailbox is full http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877060%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx and also get information about send/receive restrictions.

Depending on the type of application it's better to use Powershell (eg Get-Mailboxstatistics https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124612%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) to access any server management information about Mailbox sizes and quotas etc

Cheers
Glen

Comment: _Get-Mailboxstatistics_  is valid for ***remote access***?